# Ionic Framework - $CordivaSQLite "TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am developing an Ionic app with $cordovaSQLite installed, but when I tried running openDatabase, I got the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined".

I double checked my code that the openDatabase call is inside the $ionicPlatform.ready function and the database file has been properly installed, may I have any advices?

Thanks and Regards,

Jimmy

Comment: Where are you testing your code? On browser?

Comment: ＠Davide: I tested on my device directly by the "run android" command

Comment: Can you add the section where you call `openDatabase` function?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have ngCordova properly installed. (install instructions can be found on ngcordova website), along with the named plugin.

When you get undefined error you should always look if you have the dependency defined. That is the most common mistake with people starting with AngularJS.

Example code:

```
//inject your dependencies;
ControllerOrConfigFunction.$inject = ["$scope", "$cordovaSQLite"]

function ControllerOrConfigFunction($scope,$cordovaSQLite){
//your code here
}
```

This applies to all functions in which you are using the $cordovaSQLite plugin.
You can also find a great example on ngCordova [website](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/).

There are multiple ways you can define your Dependency Injection in AngularJs, i recommend it for now, after that take a look at ng-annotate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.cordova) {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" }); //Device
    console.log("Android");
}
else
{
    db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // Browser
    console.log("browser");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for offering help. Seeing that this is your first contribution, please take some time to learn how the platform works. Specifically, take a look at tips on [how to make your answer great](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ideally, just posting the code in itself is not very helpful - you need to add explanation as to how the code you are suggesting best addresses the question/problem.